# How can I build a Desktop client for Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to build desktop application for Windows OS and use Google Drive to save some data in the cloud. After reading Google Drive SDK I found that only Web-applications, were installed from Chrome Web Store are allowed to use API and have access to data on Google Drive.

So my question: do I have any way to build native client (C++, Windows) for Google Drive? I know about hacks with using Google Docs API - but they can stop working any time, and I want something stable. Why Google team do not allow me create desktop application for their service? I have support of many other cloud storages and they do not have such restrictions.

Thanks.

Comment: Today I'm trying the same thing; I'll let you know if any progress is made

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now you will have to use the (older) [Google Document List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) which provides full read-write and list access to Google Drive. (Google Drive and the former Google Docs use the same data)

So until we extend the capabilities of the current Drive API to cover the Google Document List use case you should use that instead.

EDIT: We just launched the v2 of the [Google Drive SDK](http://developers.google.com/drive/) so you should now use that instead.

Comment: Hi, I went to Google Drive SDK and it only shows API for iOS, Web and Android. No API for desktop though

Comment: True. Is Desktop API available?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a similar problem. I have realized that there is no straight forward way for doing this. Google Drive SDK is not easy to work with and how someone can simplify the process of connecting desktop application to Google drive shortly. I know this is not much help, but I am looking for a soltuion as well.

Here is some links that I have come across, haven't solved my problem either, but if you come to a solution please let us know PLEASE:

[How to make GUI Client to upload file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152256/how-to-make-gui-client-to-upload-file-in-java)

[Using Java APIs for downloading file from the Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235104/using-java-apis-for-downloading-file-from-the-google-drive)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/643120/Servlets/java/upload-file-drop-box-file