# How to make GUI Client to upload file in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, serversocket

Please help me I want to make a GUI application which upload a file from client to server.
when I click on browse button then file is copy in bytes form because we travel data in bytes on network but when I click on upload button then file cannot upload.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClientUpload extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFileChooser fc;
    JButton b, b1;
    JTextField tf;
    FileInputStream in;
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    DataInputStream din;
    int i;

    ClientUpload() {
        super("client");
        tf = new JTextField();
        tf.setBounds(20, 50, 190, 30);
        add(tf);

        b = new JButton("Browse");
        b.setBounds(250, 50, 80, 30);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        b1 = new JButton("Upload");
        b1.setBounds(250, 100, 80, 30);
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        fc = new JFileChooser();
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 10);
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            send();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if (e.getSource() == b) {
                int x = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (x == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    copy();
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                send();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public void copy() throws IOException {
        File f1 = fc.getSelectedFile();
        tf.setText(f1.getAbsolutePath());
        in = new FileInputStream(f1.getAbsolutePath());
        while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }

    public void send() throws IOException {
        dout.write(i);
        dout.flush();

    }

    public static void main(String... d) {
        new ClientUpload();
    }
}
```

Comment: A file is likely to more then a single `int` long...

Comment: In my view you should use [Apache httpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). It will give you so many features easly.

Comment: @Manish While I would never argue the power of HTTPClient...where does this look like HTTP is involved?

Comment: oh got it..my mistake.As You are talking about file uploading thats why I talked about `Apache httpClient.` You can upload file using that.

Comment: @Manish You may be right yet ;)

Comment: The question is a little deceiving. GUI or non GUI client is quite irrelevant. The environment of the server is important tell us if the server runs an ftp daemon and/or a web server.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically reading the contents of the file when you select it, discard the contents and then trying to send the last `int` value you read from it to the server.  A file my be many, many, many bytes long (think giga bytes), an `int` ins't going to hold that much information (poor `int`).

Instead, when the user selects a `File`, you should maintain a reference to it until you actually need it...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            int x = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (x == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileToBeSent = fc.getSelectedFile();
                tf.setText(f1.getAbsolutePath());
                b1.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                fileToBeSent = null;
                tf.setText(null;);
                b1.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            send();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

When the user presses the "send" button, you would simply copy the file input stream to the sockets output stream...

```
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(fileToBeSent);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesIn = -1;
    while ((bytesIn = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        dout.write(buffer, 0, bytesIn);
    }
    dout.flush();
} finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

That should at least get you one step closer.

The next problem you are likely to hit is the fact that the UI will stop responding while the transfer is underway.

In this case, you should take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Modern UI's need to deal with many different characteristics of client machines, included different fonts, font rendering capabilities, DPI, screen resolutions and lots more.  You're putting your self in a very dark and deep hole by using absolute layouts.

You should take advantage of the layout manager API which is designed to easy the pressure of these concerns and make you UI more accommodating on different operating environments.

Take a look at [Layout out Components within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more deatils

You may also want to take a closer look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [All about sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) for more details...

Comment: is there a typo in third line -> _thing giga bytes_ ?

Answer (score 1):

You Just Copy and paste this code this will help you ....

#### This is Server class

```
package newpack;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SwingControlServer extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SwingControlServer frame = new SwingControlServer();
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected static void start() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         System.out.println("Server running...");
         
            /* Listen on port 5555 */
     
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(10001);
     
            /* Accept the sk */
     
            Socket socket = server.accept();
           
            System.out.println("Server accepted client");
            InputStream inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
            byte[] readbyte=new byte[(1024*10)*1024];           
            
                
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream("D:/Manoj/hello21.zip");
            int writebyte;
            int count=0;
            while((writebyte=inputStream.read(readbyte))!=-1)
            {
                if(writebyte>0)
                    count+=writebyte;
                fileOutputStream.write(readbyte, 0, writebyte);
            }
            
            //System.out.println("THE WRITEBYTE VALUE IS "+writebyte+"THE READ BYTE VALUE IS"+count);
            inputStream.close();
            System.out.println("CONNECTION CLOSED");
            

        
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public SwingControlServer() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        
    }


}
```

#### This is Client Class

```
package newpack;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


 
public class SwingControlDemo extends JFrame {
    
   /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame mainFrame;
   private JPanel controlPanel;
   private String filename;
   private String fname;
   private JProgressBar progressBar;
   private Task task;
   private JButton startButton;
   private JTextArea outputTextArea;
   private JTextField textField;
   private JLabel lblFilename;
   private JButton btnNewButton;
   private JButton btnCancel;
   private JLabel sendinglabel;
   private JLabel starttime;
   private JLabel endtime;
private JLabel sendinglabel1;
   
   
   public SwingControlDemo(){
      prepareGUI();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      SwingControlDemo  swingControlDemo = new SwingControlDemo();      
      swingControlDemo.showProgressBarDemo();
   }

   private void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Large File Upload");
      mainFrame.setSize(492,400);
      mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });
      mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

      controlPanel = new JPanel();
      controlPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 491, 355);
      mainFrame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel);
      controlPanel.setLayout(null);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   
   
   private void showProgressBarDemo(){
      controlPanel.setLayout(null);
      
      textField = new JTextField();
      textField.setBounds(125, 26, 105, 31);
      controlPanel.add(textField);
      textField.setColumns(10);
      
        sendinglabel=new JLabel("FIle is Sending...");
        sendinglabel.setBounds(10, 128, 168, 30);
        sendinglabel.setVisible(false);
        sendinglabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        controlPanel.add(sendinglabel);
        
        sendinglabel1=new JLabel("FIle is Sending...");
        sendinglabel1.setBounds(51, 200, 250, 30);
        sendinglabel1.setVisible(false);
        sendinglabel1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        controlPanel.add(sendinglabel1);
        
        
        endtime = new JLabel("");
        endtime.setBounds(204, 200, 208, 33);
        endtime.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        controlPanel.add(endtime);
        
        
        starttime = new JLabel("");
        starttime.setBounds(273, 141, 208, 33);
        starttime.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        controlPanel.add(starttime);
        
      ProgressMonitor pc=new ProgressMonitor(SwingControlDemo.this, "Running My Program","", 0,10);
      
            
                  progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
                  progressBar.setBounds(62, 158, 146, 31);
                  progressBar.setValue(0);
                  progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
                  controlPanel.add(progressBar);
                  
                  
                  startButton = new JButton("Send");
                  startButton.setBounds(75, 82, 90, 31);
                  startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  private int i;

                @Override
                
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    
                    task = new Task();                
                    task.start();
                    
                }});
                  
                        controlPanel.add(startButton);
                        
                              outputTextArea = new JTextArea("",5,20);
                              outputTextArea.setVisible(false);
                              outputTextArea.setBounds(51, 200, 164, 94);
                              controlPanel.add(outputTextArea);
                              
                              lblFilename = new JLabel("FileName");
                              lblFilename.setVisible(true);
                              lblFilename.setBounds(10, 26, 105, 31);
                              lblFilename.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                              controlPanel.add(lblFilename);
                              
                              
                              btnNewButton = new JButton("Browse");
                              btnNewButton.setBounds(258, 26, 105, 31);
                              btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                

                                

                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                    
                                    JFileChooser filedilg=new JFileChooser();
                                    filedilg.showOpenDialog(filedilg);
                                    filename=filedilg.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                                    textField.setText(filename);
                                    
                                    File file1=new File(filename);
                                    fname = file1.getName();           
                                    System.out.println("THE FILE NAME IS "+fname);
                                }
                              });
                              btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                              controlPanel.add(btnNewButton);
                              
                              btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
                              btnCancel.setBounds(182, 82, 90, 31);
                              btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                System.exit(0); 
                                }
                            });
                              controlPanel.add(btnCancel);
                              mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   private class Task extends Thread {    
      public Task(){   }     

    public void run(){       
        
        PrintStream ps = null;      
        if(filename!=null)
        {
            DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            String starttime=df.format(c.getTime());
            System.out.println("Start time: "+starttime);
            
         try{
//To get current working directory
            String workingdirectory=System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println(workingdirectory);
//Create folder name as LogFolder in workingdirectory
            File file1=new File(workingdirectory+"\\LogFolder\\");
            
            File f2 = null;         
            //if folder not present we need to create a folder
            if (!file1.exists()) {
                if (file1.mkdir()) {
                    f2=new File(file1, "abc.txt");
                    System.out.println("Directory is created!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
                }
                
            }f2=new File(file1, "abc.txt");
            ps=new PrintStream(f2);
            
                /* Try to connect to the server on localhost, port 5555 */
            sendinglabel.setVisible(true);
            SwingControlDemo.this.starttime.setText("Start time: "+starttime);
             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "File is Sending...!!!");
            
          
           
            
            
            
                Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",10001);
                
                File file=new File(filename);
                             
               
              
                
                 
                double size=(file.length()/(1024*1024));
                //float size1=(float)size;  
                
                System.out.println("THE FILE SIZE IS "+size);
                //iterate();

                

                    byte[] mybyte=new byte[(int) file.length()];
                    
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(file);
                    int count;
                    int i=0;
                    OutputStream outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
                    
                    while((count=fileInputStream.read(mybyte))!=-1)
                    {
                        outputStream.write(mybyte);
                        i+=1;
                        
                        System.out.print("FIle Sent........"+i+"Kilobytes \t");
                        myFun(i, size);
                        
                    
                    
                }
                System.out.println();
                
                DateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
                String endtime=df1.format(c1.getTime());
                System.out.println("End time is : "+endtime);
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "File Sent Successfully!!!!\n Start Time is :"+starttime+"\n End Time Is : "+endtime);
                SwingControlDemo.this.endtime.setText(endtime);
                System.out.println("THIS FILE HAS BEEN SENT SUCCESSFULLY!!!");      
                
                

                socket.close();
                System.exit(1);
                
            

            }
        
            catch (Exception ex){
                /* Catch any errors */

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error While Sending File : "+ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace(ps);
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please Choose a Valid File");
        }
                    
        
        
        
        
         
      }

    private  void myFun(int j,Double mbsize) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        int per=(int) ((j*100)/mbsize);
        System.out.println("THE INTEGER VALUE IS "+per);
        if(j<mbsize)
        {
            System.out.println("INSIDE IF LOOP");
            progressBar.setValue(per);
            
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar.setValue(per);
            
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            
           
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
         
      }
        
    }
   }
```