# Java Application Upload to Linux Server

Tags: java, linux, server

i couldnt find any answers to my question yet, so im asking you guys.
Is there a way to do following:
I want to have someone click a button in my Java Application/Program done with JFrame... i got everything setup...now when you click the button it sends a .txt file from you local drive to the linux server, so its in a random folder on the server.

I hope thats possible and not too confusing.

I got a Linux Server and everything setup i just need a way to upload a file to the server.

Yours David

Comment: If you haven't coded anything yet, here's one to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/q/19152256/1248974

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. You might need SCP or SFTP Java clients. The one which I used for the similar purpose is com.jcraft.jsch.