# How to connect Java desktop application to cloud?

Tags: java, netbeans, cloud, google-cloud-storage, desktop-application

I have been asked to develop a desktop application which will connect to the cloud. The desktop application will need to upload and download files to and from the cloud storage.

I have developed the interface which is simplistic and easy to use. It allows the user to upload a file (any format) to the cloud by selecting the file on the host computer and storing it on the cloud. The interface shows a list of files which will be stored on the cloud, then the user can select a file from the cloud and download such to the host computer.

I am struggling to identify the correct way of connecting the desktop application to the cloud such as google drive cloud or Dropbox cloud. Can anyone please advise me on which SDK or way in which I will need to use to connect the app to the cloud.

I have seen that there is many web based applications, but I need the application to be desktop based and just connect to the cloud for files.

It would be tremendously helpful if someone would be able to help me out with the connection to the cloud and I can work from there.

- Which API or SDK to use
- Connecting desktop application to cloud for file access
- How to specify username and password for cloud access

I would appreciate any help or information which anyone can provide in helping me connect my desktop application to the cloud server such as Google cloud.

I apologize upfront for not being very specific, I have tried to make my question as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a little overwhelming to search for the documentation, especially when you are just starting up.

You can sign up for the free trial on Google Storage (for example). See [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).

Then, you can follow a supposedly straightforward tutorial (assuming you are doing a Java standalone/desktop app) [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/using-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi for your problem it will help you to use Google Cloud API with your desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is common. I have been struggling with the same problem for a while now and still unable to accomplish it. I have managed to get the download coding from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235104/using-java-apis-for-downloading-file-from-the-google-drive) but still unable to get the connection to google drive working. If you look at [GUI client upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152256/how-to-make-gui-client-to-upload-file-in-java) on the last answer on the page, it has some coding that allows the user to connect and upload to a server. But maybe if you or someone can edit this to work with Google drive, it will be helpful